# Privacy Secrity for training model when using federated learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow-federated

Does federated learning provide privacy securities for the model being trained?

Answer (score 0):

The tff package provides basic [Federated Averaging](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05629) tutorials.
You can add secure model aggregation techniques by combining tensorflow encrypted with tff.